# Computer vision: if my camera has field of view for X pixel image, is X/2 pixels half the field of view?

Tags: geometry, computer-vision

I have a camera for a computer vision application that I know has e.g. a 60 degree field of view. It captures images that are 640 pixels wide.

My question then is if I crop the central half of pixels, at 320 pixels wide, is it fair to say that what is shown in this crop corresponds to a 30 degree field of view?

And would the ratios continue to work like that? Or am I missing some trigonometry here? I added a picture below to try and help explain my question.

[image]

Help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a coordinate system where the origin is along the image axis, $x$ coordinate and the angle $\theta$ are related by
$$\tan\theta = \frac{x}{d} \quad \iff \quad x = d \tan\theta$$

If for $x = 320$ we have $\theta = 30^\circ$, then
$$d = \frac{320}{\tan 30^\circ} = 320 \sqrt{3} \approx 554.256$$
and
$$x = 320 \sqrt{3} \tan\left(\theta\right) \quad \iff \quad \theta = \arctan\left(\frac{x}{320 \sqrt{3}}\right)$$
In other words, if the $640$-pixel wide image corresponds to an angle of $60^\circ$, the $320$-pixel wide center part corresponds to an angle of approximately $32.2^\circ$.

This is based on the properties of 3D projection, assuming a perfect lens system (similar to a pinhole camera); and is not an approximation.